# POWER BI: Exporting measures into own data table on daily basis

Tags: export, powerbi

I have connected my power BI to companys oracle database, and with measure I have calculated the daily inventory level. My problem is that I only have the current inventory level in my power BI which updates automatically when i press refresh. (no historic data)

Is it possible to somehow export the measurements data (inventory level) to a new table where there could be for example a date and a inventory level from that certain date.

At the endpoint there would be historic data in one table about the development of our companys inventory levels.

Comment: No such options within Power BI, I'd recommend creating a Log table with the historic information in your DB and perhaps running a job/sp to update it periodically

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get measure values with recently announced [XMLA Endpoint](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-open-platform-connectivity-with-xmla-endpoints-public-preview/) , but you need Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded capacity for that to work (at least for now).

Other way of doing this could be with an Excel file and [Analyse with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-analyze-in-excel) -feature. For this to work, you need to update the excel file and save the results manually.

Third option is the way @MJoy suggested, a log table to the source database with automatic updates.